# How do I find out if/where xlsxwriter is on my system (for python)?

Tags: python, excel, python-extensions

I am attempting to use the xlsxwriter package to write and image to an eXcel file, but I keep getting the 'No module name 'xlsxwriter' error on the import statement.  I am on a closed network, so I am wondering also how I can find out where xlsxwriter is on my system as well as what other packages/extensions are available on my system.  Thanks for reading my post - any help, ideas, or suggestions are greatly appreciated!  Thanks, Don

Comment: You are getting an error that says the xlsxwriter module doesn't exist, why do you assume that it does?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am relatively new at python, but have been programming a long time.  Most all of the documentation/examples on the internet references using 'xlsxwriter' package in python for writing images to eXcel files (and this is what I want to do).  Since I am getting the error, I am looking for where the package is/could be on my closed system (and I am also curious about what other packages are available for me to use in my python scripts).

Comment: `xlsxwriter` is not a built-in Python module. You have to install it as explained in the docs: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/getting_started.html